# Extract relevant text from pdf files using Regex -python

Tags: python

i am new at using python and need help with the code below. I am trying to develop a code to extract data from multiple pdf documents (similar format) in a folder in a loop.

Would really appreciate if someone can help with resolving the issue here.

I am currently getting following error msg when I run the code;

Traceback (most recent call last):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pdf_file'
...................................................................

The above problem was resolved, thanks to  Tim Roberts and furas.

I am currently stuck at last step to extract the relevant text from a string and getting an error message of None. I have attached text string and expected results and python code 2 used to extract.
5 out 6 months the same code worked. However for month of May it is giving me "None"

Please could someone help.

.....
string

" DateAsOn 31-May-21\n Period 01-May-21to31-May-21\nBAddress \nStatementofBankingAccount\nDate Narration Chq /Ref. No Withdrawal(Dr) Deposit(Cr) Balance\n01-May-2021OPENINGBALANCE... 140,838.50 140,838.50(Cr)\n12-May-2021AP:BILLPAYFORBESCOM0284751635 EBPP-0284751635 3,519.00 137,319.50(Cr)\n19-May-2021NACH-10-CR-HCLTECHNOLOGIESLIM-452962 NACHDB190521000 5,760.00 143,079.50(Cr)\n56107\nClosingBalance 143,079.50 (Cr)\nHoldbalance-Charges 0.00 (Cr)\nHoldbalance-Others 0.00 (Cr)\nAverageMonthly/QuarterlyBalance 140,983.66 (Cr)\nClosingBalanceofSweepTD 0.00 (Cr)\nBankdepositofuptoRs.500,000withrespecttoeachdepositorisfullyprotectedbytheDepositInsuranceandCreditGuaranteeCorporationundertheDepositInsuranceScheme.(cid:13)\nEffectiveJuly1,2017,GSThasbeenleviedonthechargesattheprescribedrateof18%.Pleasenotethatthisstatement/adviceshouldnotbeconstruedasa`TaxInvoice'underthe\nGoodsandServicesTaxAct.\n(cid:13)\n(cid:13)Dear Customer,asperGovernment'sdirective,ifthePANisnotlinkedwiththeAadhaarbyJune30,2021thenthePANwillbecomeinoperative.Kindlyvisitthee-filingportalofthe\nIncomeTaxdept.&linkyourAADHAARwithPANtoavoidanyadverseconsequencesandissuesinfuture.Non-linkingofPANwithAadhaarwillresultinhigherTDS(Tax\nDeductedatSource)/TCS(TaxCollectedatSource)andtheBankshallbeconstrainedtorestrictoperationsintheAccount/sheldbyyou.(cid:13)\nRBIhasadvisedBankstomakethefacilityofPositivePayavailabletocustomersissuinghighvaluecheques.EffectiveJanuary1,2021,customerswillberequiredtoprovidedetails\nforallchequesissuedbythemviaNetBanking/MobileBanking/atthebranchonthesamedayoftheissuanceorbeforeitishandedovertothebeneficiary.Formoredetails,visit\nwww.kotak.com(cid:13)\nDearCustomer,dokeepsufficientbalanceinyourA/catthestartofthedayofascheduledNACHpaymenttoavoidanyreturnsduetolackoffunds.Forqueries,callourCustomer\nContactCentreorvisitthenearestBankbranch.\nThisissystemgeneratedreportanddoesnotrequiresignatureandstamp\nAnydiscrepancyinthestatementshouldbebroughttothenoticeofKotakMahindraBankLtd.withinonemonthfromdateofstatement\nCommonlyUsedNarrations:ATL-OtherBankATMWithdrawal,ATW-KotakATMWithdrawal,BP-BillPaytransaction,CDM-KotakCashDepositMachine,IB-InternetBankingtransaction,MB-MobileBanking\nTransaction,Netcard-Netc@rdtransaction,OS-OnlineShoppingtransaction,PB-PhoneBanking,PCI/PCD-POStransaction,VISACCPAY-VisaCreditCardPayment"

---

Expected result will look like this;
01-May-2021
OPENINGBALANCE...
140,838.50
140,838.50
(Cr)
12-May-2021
AP:BILLPAYFORBESCOM0284751635 EBPP-0284751635
3,519.00
137,319.50
(Cr)
19-May-2021
NACH-10-CR-HCLTECHNOLOGIESLIM-452962 NACHDB190521000
5,760.00
143,079.50
(Cr)

```
    enter code here
```

** Python code 1

```
def extract_pdf(path):
        with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
            for pdf_page in pdf.pages:
                BS_Kotak_extract = pdf_page.extract_text()
        return(BS_Kotak_extract)  

folder_path_pdf_file ='/home/sameer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Kotak Statements'
    for pdf_file in os.listdir(folder_path_pdf_file):
        print(pdf_file)
        Kotak_BT= extract_pdf('pdf_file')
```

---

python code 2

```
path='/home/sameer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Kotak Statements/May-21_560037.pdf'
s= extract_pdf(path)
print(s)


BS_Kotak = namedtuple('BS_Kotak', 'Date Description Transaction_Amount Balance Balance_Dr_Cr')
line_items = []
Pattern_BankTransactions_1 = re.compile(r'([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}-[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{2,4})(.*)')
for line in s.split('\n'):
    line = Pattern_BankTransactions_1.search(line)
    print(line)
    if line:
        print(line.group(1))
        date = line.group(1)
        desc = line.group(2)
        Trans_amt = line.group(3)
        bal_amt = line.group(4)
        bal_dr_cr = line.group(5)
        line_items.append(BS_Kotak(date, desc, Trans_amt, bal_amt, bal_dr_cr))
        print(date)
        print(desc)
        print(Trans_amt)
        print(bal_amt)
        print(bal_dr_cr)
```

Comment: Don't put the variable name in quotes.  Do `Kotak_BT = extract_pdf(pdf_file)`.  Or, more accurately. `Kotak_BT = extract_pdf(folder_path_pdf_file+"/"+pdf_file)`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, change you suggested worked.  However, I have 6 pdf files from Jan-July in the folder but the code is extracting the same file (July) and returning the extract 6 times. How can I get the code to loop to extract data for each month.

Comment: if you run loop then you should use `list` to get all results. Now you always assign values to the same variable `Kotak_BT` so you get only last value. The same with for-loop in `extract_pdf` and variable `BS_Kotak_extract` - it get only last page. You should also use `list` and `append()` to this list. OR if you have strings then you should create empty string before loop `BS_Kotak_extract = ""` and add to this string `BS_Kotak_extract += pdf_page.extract_text()`

Comment: Thanks furas, it worked. I am stuck at next step, i have added the problem in the body of the question. Can you please help?

Comment: Don't move the goal posts. Ask a new question if you have a new problem. But search for existing questions first.

Comment: Thanks tripleee, understood! I am new to programing and stack overflow, will get used to.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).